# Eigenvalues of Eigenvectors of Projection and Reflection Matrices

Tags: orthogonality, projection, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

Suppose I have some matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$, and I'm interested in the matrix $P$, which orthogonally projects all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $\mathcal{R}(A)$ (i.e. the column space of A), as well as the matrix $R$ which reflects vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ through $\mathcal{R}(A)$.

From a simple geometric argument (or the fact that with orthogonal projection matrices $M$ we have $M^T = M$ and $M^2 = M$, if you'd like), we can immediately gauge that the eigenvalues of $P$ are 0 and 1 (each with geometric multiplicity of 2) and the eigenvalues of $R$ are -1 and 1 (again each with geometric multiplicity of 2).

Now I was wondering:
1) Can we compute the corresponding eigenvectors of $P$ and $R$ without computing each of those matrices explicitly?
2) Can we determine a basis for the null space and the column space of $P$ directly from $A$?
3) Can we conclude that $P$ is invertible? Naturally, $R$ is invertible through another simple geometric argument, but I can't see something like this immediately for $P$.

Apologies if these 3 questions should be separate questions, but I thought maybe their solutions would build on each other, or at least give some intuition.

Comment: The other Eigenspace is just the orthogonal of A, which answers 1 and 2. P is not invertible unless the null space is the 0 vector.

Comment: The eigenspace corresponding to which eigenvalue(s)? Can you expand on your comments in an answer?

Comment: As far as invertibility goes, do you know the relationship of the determinant of a matrix to its eigenvalues?

Comment: Ah indeed, I overlooked that one. $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix, and hence diagonalizable. Then the determinant of $P$ is simply the determinant of its diagonal matrix, and hence the product of those diagonal entries (its eigenvalues). Since $0$ is an eigenvalue, it follows that $P$ is not invertible. That deals with 3) nicely.